# AWS EC2 Permissions Denied /usr/local/bin cURL

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to follow [this](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/) documentation and install docker machine on my EC2 instance. However, the curl command:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.8.2/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

quits with the error:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-machine: Permission denied

I tried to curl into the home directory, hoping that it would change the permissions on the directory and then copy it to destination, but it didn't work.

How can I by-pass this? Clearly, the ec2-user is lacking the root privileges on some directories.

Comment: Assuming you actually want to potentially overwrite any existing `/usr/local/bin/docker-machine`, you can prefix the command with `sudo` (assuming you have `sudo` privileges).

Comment: Since this is EC2 instance, I only have ec2-user access. That is, I am not sure how to become sudo in this case.

Comment: Have you tried http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html?

Comment: I already have docker installed. I need to add docker-machine which is missing for some reason. I also do not want to run anything in container yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -v   When given the -v (validate) option, sudo will update the user's cached credentials, authenticating the user's password if necessary. 
>   For the sudoers plugin, this extends the sudo timeout for another 5
>   minutes (or whatever the timeout is set to by the security policy) but
>   does not run a command. Not all security policies support cached
>   credentials.

`ec2-user` is in sudoers list by default.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo -v
[ec2-user ~]$
```

Try this:

```
sudo bash -c "curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.8.2/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine"
```

If you want to make the saved file an executable for all:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Comment: The command you gave works. However, either because of the existing permissions of the previous directory that I copied there or because of the result of this command, the permissions on `/usr/local/bin/docker-machine` are `-rw-r--r--` Hence, when I run `docker-machine version` I still get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-machine: Permission denied` Is there a way to change permissions on it using `sudo bash -c`?

Comment: Thanks @helloV! Looks like I was after `sudo -v` and this. Much appreciated!

Comment: P.S. Live and learn ... I never thought `sudo` command had flags :-)